# memcache fast-cgi php apache 2.2 windows 7 creating problems

Tags: php, apache, memcached, fastcgi

i am trying to run memcache, fast-cgi with apache 2.2 + php on a windows 7 machine. if i dont use memcache everything works fine.

the moment i disable extension=php_memcache.dll in php.ini everything returns to normal.

once i start apache, the apache logs say:

```
[Wed Jan 12 18:19:23 2011] [notice] Apache/2.2.17 (Win32) mod_fcgid/2.3.6 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Jan 12 18:19:23 2011] [notice] Server built: Oct 18 2010 01:58:12
[Wed Jan 12 18:19:23 2011] [notice] Parent: Created child process 412
[Wed Jan 12 18:19:23 2011] [notice] Child 412: Child process is running
[Wed Jan 12 18:19:23 2011] [notice] Child 412: Acquired the start mutex.
[Wed Jan 12 18:19:23 2011] [notice] Child 412: Starting 64 worker threads.
[Wed Jan 12 18:19:23 2011] [notice] Child 412: Starting thread to listen on port 80.
```

and after accessing the page [the page just has echo phpinfo()]. i get this error in the error.log

```
[Wed Jan 12 18:20:54 2011] [warn] [client 127.0.0.1] (OS 109)The pipe has been ended.  : mod_fcgid: get overlap result error
[Wed Jan 12 18:20:54 2011] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Premature end of script headers: index.php
```

i have php_memcache.dll in my ext directory and httpd.conf is like this:

```
LoadModule fcgid_module modules/mod_fcgid.so

FcgidInitialEnv PHPRC "c:/php"
FcgidInitialEnv PATH "c:/php;C:/WINDOWS/system32;C:/WINDOWS;C:/WINDOWS/System32/Wbem;"
FcgidInitialEnv SystemRoot "C:/Windows"
FcgidInitialEnv SystemDrive "C:"
FcgidInitialEnv TEMP "C:/WINDOWS/Temp"
FcgidInitialEnv TMP "C:/WINDOWS/Temp"
FcgidInitialEnv windir "C:/WINDOWS"
FcgidIOTimeout 64
FcgidConnectTimeout 32
FcgidMaxRequestsPerProcess 500

<Files ~ "\.php$>"
  AddHandler fcgid-script .php
  FcgidWrapper "c:/php/php-cgi.exe" .php
</Files>
```

so the problem has to be related to memcache coz if i disable it, fast-cgi seems to be working fine. any possible reasons for this??

the memcache service is running.. i can check it through control panel->services

Answer (score 1, accepted):

posted it on server fault.. but anyways found the solution myself.. please refer to https://serverfault.com/questions/221858/memcache-fast-cgi-php-apache-2-2-windows-7-creating-problems